# I think I solved an old problem, can someone please check it for me?

Tags: discussion

Sorry if this is inappropriate to ask on meta, but back in April I updated an old answer of mine that is over two years old [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16857/existence-of-a-zero-sum-subset/38997#38997), on the existence of a zero sum subset problem.  I suspect due to how old this question is, no one has  even noticed that I updated my answer.

I believe I have given a correct solution, but being as I am not a professional mathematician, I have been unable to find a qualified person to check it for me.  If anyone would be willing to give some feedback it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You likely should notify OP of the question (via a comment on the question) or perhaps still better (as it works in this case) via a comment (directed at them) on your answer.

Comment: On an unrelated note, it seems you have two accounts, one of which is unregistered.  Perhaps you should ask the moderators to merge your accounts.

Comment: We no longer merge accounts ourselves. Writing to community@stackexchange.com with the details of the pair of accounts usually results in prompt action, however!

Comment: I am grateful that David Speyer has responded in comments and although my approach may end up working out, as posted it is not a correct solution. I will however continue working on the problem.